# Writing a blob with Esri.FileGDB.Row.SetBinary return an empty value when reread the blob field

Tags: file-geodatabase-api

I am trying to write an image/png in an ESRI FileGDB field.

I use the Esri.FileGDB.API 1.4, both 32/64, in C#.

The type of the field is "esriFieldTypeBlob".

I am currently able to write the image, without errors, as follows:

```
Table table = gdb.OpenTable(tablename);
Row newRow = table.CreateRowObject();
byte[] fba = null;
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgpath);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    fba = ms.ToArray();
}
ByteArray ba = new ByteArray((uint) fba.Length);
ba.byteArray = (byte[]) fba.Clone();
newRow.SetBinary(fieldname, ba);
table.Insert(newRow);
```

But when I re-read the field using GetBinary, the ByteArray is 0 length.

What am I doing wrong?

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the FGDB row with Desktop?

Comment: Yes. The field is empty.

Comment: Try adding a diagnostic print statement to check the input length. Is the "empty" field NULL or is a BLOB with length zero?

Comment: The field is not NULL. Is a BLOB with length zero.

Comment: So the query results in the same value which was inserted?  Please edit the question to reflect this information, and explain why this is a problem.

Comment: The query results is NOT the same value which was inserted. Value inserted: ByteArray with length of 76388. Value reread: ByteArray with length 0. This is the problem...

Comment: Then **edit the question** to provide this information.  I've read and written every supported datatype with the C++ API, so I don't think this is a common problem. The support mechanism is to post to GeoNet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you populate the ByteArray with

```
ba.byteArray = (byte[]) fba.Clone();
```

the property ba.inUseLength remain 0.
To solve the problem you can set it manually :

```
ba.byteArray = (byte[]) fba.Clone();
ba.inUseLength = ba.allocatedLength;
```

With this workaround i can write and reread the blob field.

Comment: You are right, it works now... Thanks for the solution.